# $u$ is a projection on $B(H)$ and $\overline{\text{Ran}(qp)}=\overline{\text{Ran}(u)}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, projection

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $B(H)$ be the space of all bounded operators on $H$. Let $p$ and $q$ are two projections on $B(H)$. Now define an operator $u$ on $B(H)$ by:
$$u:=q-\inf\{q,1-p\}.$$
I want to prove that $u$ is a projection on $B(H)$ and $\overline{\text{Ran}(qp)}=\overline{\text{Ran}(u)},$ where ${\text{Ran}(qp)}$ and $\text{Ran}(u)$ are ranges of $qp$ and $u$ respectively.

In order to show that $u$ is a projection, I need to show that $u^*=u$ and $u^2=u$. Please help me to solve this and also $\overline{\text{Ran}(qp)}=\overline{\text{Ran}(u)}$. Thank you for your help.

**Def:** For any projections $p,q \in B(H)$, the operator $\inf\{p,q\}$ is the projection from $H$ to $\left(pH\cap qH\right)$.

Comment: What is your definition of $\inf \{q,I-p\}$ here? They are both operators.

Comment: @K.Power Sir, I have updated the definition in my question.

Answer (score 1):

It is [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/139689/22857) that
$$
\inf\{q,1-p\}=q\wedge (1-p)=\lim_{\rm sot} (q(1-p)q)^n.
$$
Thus $u$ (which is a projection by definition), satisfies
$$\tag1
u=\lim_{\rm sot}q-(q(1-p)q)^n. 
$$
This shows that $qu=u$; in particular, taking adjoints, $uq=u$.
Also, from $(1)$,
$$
u=\lim_{\rm sot}q-(q(1-p)q)^n
=\lim_{\rm sot}q(1-((1-p)q(1-p))^n). 
$$
Thus $up=qp$. This shows that $\operatorname{ran}qp\subset\operatorname{ran}u$.

Now suppose that $\xi\in\operatorname{ran} u\ominus \overline{\operatorname{span}}qp$. This means that
$$\tag2
\xi=q\xi-(q\wedge(1-p))\xi
$$
and
$$\tag3
\langle \xi,qp\eta\rangle=0,\ \eta\in H. 
$$
We can rewrite $(3)$ as $\langle pq\xi,\eta\rangle=0$ for all $\eta$, so
$$\tag5
pq\xi=0.
$$
Then
$$
p\xi=-p(q\wedge(1-p))\xi=0
$$
and
$$
q\xi=pq\xi+(1-p)q\xi=(1-p)q\xi. 
$$
Iterating this equality,
$$
(q(1-p)q)^n\xi=q\xi, 
$$
and taking the limit we get
$$
(q\wedge(1-p))\xi=q\xi. 
$$
Thus, by $(2)$,
$$
\xi=u\xi=q\xi-(q\wedge(1-p))\xi=q\xi-q\xi=0, 
$$
and hence $\overline{\operatorname{ran}}qp=\operatorname{ran}u$.